# Heat Equation 1D in Cylindrical Region

Tags: numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences

I have heat equation 1D in cylindrical coordinates:
$$u_{\rho\rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}u_{\rho}=u_{t},\;0<\rho<1,t>0 $$
with boundary conditions $u(1,t)=0,\;t>0$ and initial condition $u(\rho,0)=T$. I approximate $u_{\rho\rho}$ with central differences of second order and $u_{\rho}$, $u_{t}$ with central and backward-scheme. So my domain is:[image]

for $\rho\neq 0.$ If $\rho=0$ then heat equation is $$2u_{\rho\rho}=u_{t}.$$ My question is.   Why in the last case $\rho=0$ is not a boundary but a line of symmetry.

Comment: It wouldn't commonly be considered a boundary since it is not the location for a boundary condition.  It is considered a line of symmetry because the domain can be symmetrically extended to $-1 \leq \rho \leq 0$ with the identical solution, so that $T(\rho)=T(-\rho)$.